# Log the selected resource in Simmer for R

Tags: r, simulation

I'm trying to create a simulation model that describes traffic near the motorway gates.

I have added the resources

```
motorwayGate <-
    simmer("motorwayGate") %>%
    add_resource("counterCards", 1) %>%
    add_resource("counterCash1", 1) %>%
    add_resource("counterCash2", 1) %>%
    add_resource("counterCash3", 1) %>%
```

Then i let the simulation select one of the elements taking into account shortest-queue policy.

```
select(c("counterCards", "counterCash1", "counterCash2", "counterCash3"), policy = "shortest-queue") %>%
```

How to log  the value of the selected resource? I would like to know which one was selected. I've tried using

```
log_(get_selected()) %>%
```

or

```
print(get_selected())
```

but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out i was looking for a proper use of function "log_()" and "get_selected()"

```
log_(function() {paste("Selected: ", get_selected(motorwayGate))})  %>%
```